# Подскажите пожалуйста,Как реализовать вывод (1.2) на Promise?При этом не вытаскивать логику из функций

Tags: javascript, promise

```js
function one () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("1");
    },1000)
}
function two () {
        console.log("2")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function one() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("1");
      resolve();
    }, 1000)
  })
}

function two() {
  console.log("2")
}

one().then(two);
```

Comment: Можно сделать так чтобы не изменять функцию one и two?

Comment: Нет. Чтобы дождаться окончания выполнения первой функции, надо чтобы она как-то дала знать, что закончила работу. Без callback'ов, промисов или async/await этого не сделать.

Comment: Понятно ,Спасибо

Comment: Строго говоря, мой комментарий выше не совсем верен, можно придумать и другие способы (без промисов и т.п.), но все эти способы всё равно потребуют модификации хотя бы одной из функций. Например, функция может выставлять глобальный флаг, и вызывающий код должен будет перед запуском второй функции проверять этот флаг, и при необходимости откладывать вызов второй функции. Но это уже совсем извращения.

Comment: Что это за тема про флаги,как гуглить?

Comment: Да просто глобальная переменная. `funcOneFinished = true;`